# how to find how many female and male in state and how to count them with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I found how many people in one state but i don't know how to calculate the number of members within each subgroup. For example:in state 'WK' there are 16 Female and 16 Male Democrats, and 32 Female and 32 Male Republicans.
**

My Code:

```
 import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("legislators-current.csv")
member = df[['state', 'party', 'gender']].groupby(['gender', 'party'])
x = member.count()
print(x)
```

My Output:

```
gender  party       state          
F      Democrat       107
       Republican      40
M      Democrat       166
       Independent      2
       Republican     225
```

Comment: try adding party to the groupby `.groupby(['state','party'])`

Comment: Or gender (or both), depending on which groups you want to look at.

Comment: Note, I think you need 1 more data column than grouping column; so if you need to group on state, party, & gender, you need to pull down one extra column from the df.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column with State information for each member then add it to the groupby and it should work.

What you need

```
name     gender  party       state          
Anthony  M       Democrat    New York
John     M       Republican  California
Bill     M       Democrat    Texas
Angela   F       Independent California
Irina    F       Republican  New York
```

then

```py
member = df[['name', 'gender', 'party', 'state']].groupby(['gender', 'party', 'state']).count()
```